# mongod vs systemctl start mongod

Tags: 18.04, services, mongodb

When I try to start mongod as a service, it fails:

```
$ sudo service mongod start
$ sudo service mongod status
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-02-22 23:59:03 CET; 4s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 34602 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
   Main PID: 34602 (code=exited, status=14)

Feb 22 23:59:03 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Feb 22 23:59:03 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=14/n/a
Feb 22 23:59:03 ubuntu2004 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

but when I simply run mongod, my server starts and runs just fine.

```
$ sudo mongod
... (server running, writing output)
```

I am afraid that running `sudo mongod` might start a process that is located/installed somewhere else and has a different config file, but I am not sure how to find out. I also tried to check in mongo itself, but `getCmdLineOpts` is not giving me any info.

```
> db.runCommand({ getCmdLineOpts: 1 })
{ "argv" : [ "mongod" ], "parsed" : { }, "ok" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally when `status=14` is seen, it’s because the MongoDB socket file isn’t owned by `mongod`. If the very first time you started MongoDB was as `root` then there’s a chance the socket file is owned by that account.

Fortunately, it’s not too hard to fix:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Stop MongoDB:

   ```
   sudo mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer()"
   ```
3. Go to the `/tmp` directory:

   ```
   cd /tmp
   ```
4. Look for the socket file:

   ```
   ls -l mongo*.sock
   ```
5. If the owner and group are not `mongod:mongod`, then update them:

   ```
   sudo chown mongod:mongod mongodb-12345.sock
   ```

   ***Note:** If you receive an* `invalid user` *error, it means that there is no* `mongod` *user account and the database was installed under a different one. You can find the correct user in* `/etc/passwd`.
6. Restart the MongoDB service:

   ```
   sudo service mongod start
   ```

This should get the service up and running properly

Comment: I followed your steps, but I still get the error. The socket is owned by mongodb owner:
`$ls -l mongo*.sock
srwx------ 1 mongodb mongodb 0 Feb 23 10:39 mongodb-27017.sock`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by also granting the ownership to data directory and other directories that I found in my config file:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db
```

This answer was helpful to me:

[mongodb 3.4.3 Permission denied wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 267 error with ubuntu 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137250/mongodb-3-4-3-permission-denied-wiredtiger-kv-engine-cpp-267-error-with-ubuntu-1)

It seems like the reason was that I messed up the ownerships by running `mongod` with root permission.